# Save into MongoDB from views in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Hello i am facing a problem when im trying to store in my MongoDatabase some data via views.py
My question may be silly cause im new to django...

So i have a ModelForm in my **forms.py**

```
class LanModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    project_name = forms.CharField()
    target = forms.GenericIPAddressField()

class Meta:
    model = UsersInput
    fields = ('project_name', 'target',)
```

and my model in **models.py**

```
class UsersInput(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ip_subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

I submit the form and when i go to the admin page to inspect my (UsersInput) object only project name is passed. Target field is empty.

Code in **views.py**

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        _target = form.cleaned_data['target']
        project_name = form.cleaned_data['project_name']
        form.save()
  return redirect('/passive_scanning.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `views.py`

```
from .models import UsersInput

...

def post(request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        db_save = UsersInput(project_name=cd['project_name'], ip_subnet=cd['ip_subnet'])
        db_save.save()
    return redirect('/passive_scanning.html')
```

Edit `forms.py`

```
class LanModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # You do not need to declare fields here for forms.ModelForm
    class Meta:
        model = UsersInput
        fields = ('project_name', 'ip_subnet',)
```

Comment: Hm changed that and still the same thing. subnet_ip field in database is empty
Plus now it does not save it at all.

Comment: yeah my code contained error i've updated and make sure to import correctly